# Access Host Folder from Docker Container without run -v command

Tags: docker, mount

I want to share access with my host (Ubuntu) or from an nfs server and a container or image (Ubuntu). I can't use the -v command, since the container is started by a program that only allows the container name and runs it itself. Copying is not possible since the folder is big and the content might change regulary.

The nfs-mount inside of the container does throw the error: "Protocol not supported"(done the same way as on host).
Until now it got the information that a "hardcoded" mount is not possible for images and nfs-mounts might not work with docker.

I'd be open for some "hacky" solutions as well if docker might not support it.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the drive with `cifs` ? https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs
You can also try https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/kb/how-to-mount-nfs-and-cifs-file-systems-on-linux-with-the-seagate-blackarmor-nas-209791en/

Answer (score 0):

Bind mounts (the `docker run -v` option) are the only way to do this.  It's considered a major design goal and security feature of Docker that containers can't generally access the host filesystem, so it'd be a major bug if there was some way to bypass this isolation.

You need to change the calling code to include the `-v` option, or rebuild your image to embed the data you need (if it's read-only).